# How can I remove the last character of a string variable in ksh?

Tags: string, variables, ksh, var

I've a string variable and I want to remove the last character of it.

For example: pass from "testing1" to "testing".

How can I do this in KSH?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var="testing1"
print ${var%?}
```

**output**

```
testing
```

The `${var%?}` is a parameter editing feature. The '%' says remove from the right side and expects a pattern following. The pattern could be in your example case just the char '1' (without the quotes). I am using the wild-card char '?' so that any single character will be removed. You can use the '*' char to indicate all chars, but typically you want to 'bundle' that with some preceding chars, with your example `echo ${var%i*}` would give you just `test` as a result. There are also '%%' variants on this AND '#' and '##' that start from the left side of the string.

I hope this helps.

Comment: how to code this if it's in a for loop where i'th places are removed? (e.g.) input: `abcde`, 1st iteration output: `abcde`, 2nd iteration output: `abcd`, 3rd iteration output: `abc`)

Comment: `var="abcde" ; for i in {1..2} ; do var=${var%%?} ; done ; echo $var` .This will work for ksh, not sure about `bash`.  Or our cuse if you know you want to remove 3 chars at the end `echo ${var%%???}` Good luck.